# Image side by side with multiple texts with no table boundries iText PDF

Tags: java, android, itext

[image]

I am trying to set the text side by side with the image but can't do that

**Image**

```
try {
    resultBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);
    userImage = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
    userImage.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_RIGHT );
    userImage.scaleToFit(280 , 280);
}catch (Exception c){

}
```

**Multiple Text**

```
   document.add(new Paragraph("Name : "+ personal_info_data.getString("FN" , "")));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Date Of Birth : "+ personal_info_data.getString("DOB" , "")));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Birth Place : "+ personal_info_data.getString("B" , "")));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Nationality : "+ personal_info_data.getString("N" , "")));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Phone Number : "+ personal_info_data.getString("PN" , "")));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Email : "+ personal_info_data.getString("EA" , "")));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Address : "+ personal_info_data.getString("A" , "")));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Current Place : "+ personal_info_data.getString("CP" , "")));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Martial Status : "+ personal_info_data.getString("MS" , "")));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Self Description : "+ personal_info_data.getString("SI" , "")));
```

As shown in the image i want all the texts side by side with image but i don't want to implement tables i need no boundries .. Any way how can i accomplish this .

Answer (score -1):

You can do that in 2 way.

1. setting `TextView` and `ImageView` in `xml` file as below

inside your `RelativeLayout` in `xml` file

add `ImageView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
   android:layout_width="150dp"
   android:layout_height="150dp"
   android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Give `TextView` for each field and assign it a value programmatically by
`textView.setText(text);`

2. You can create layout file as below and add views to `LinearLayout` programmatically as below.

xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="150dp"
       android:layout_height="150dp"
       android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java file.

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
    textView1.setText("Name");
    linearLayout.addView(textView1);
    TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
    textView2.setText("Email");
    linearLayout.addView(textView2);
```

put it in `onCreate` and add as many views as you need.

then you will get it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v45nS.png)

Comment: Did you read the OP's Question before answering the android code?